# Java: JPanel doesn't pick up keyboard bindings

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keyevent, miglayout

## Problem

I've been fiddling to make keybindings work properly in an application I've written.

Previously, I've been using a variant of the following; 
    `panel.registerKeyboardAction(this, "createNewFood", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);`

But since I read in the documentation that registerKeyboardAction was marked as deprecated, I tried switching to the preferred method, which goes something like this;
    `panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control I"), new NewFoodAction());`

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working.

## What I've Tried

I've searched the web and I've tried a bunch of different approaches unsuccessfully;

- Instead of binding the key to the panel I tried attaching it to the result of `getRootPane()`. Didn't work.
- I've tried all of the different "conditions"; `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`, `WHEN_FOCUSED`, didn't work.
- I tried setting `panel.setFocusable(true)`; didn't work.
- I tried using `panel.requestFocusInWindow()` just to see if it could work conditionally; didn't work.

If I attach the keybinding to another component, for instance a JTextField, then it works as it's supposed to.

**Some other information that *might* be relevant** (but I don't really think it is);

- I'm using MigLayout for the panel. Don't think this affects anything but who knows.
- I have other keybindings present (that is, other keystrokes bound to other components)

Here's some sample code:

```
public FoodFrame() {
    super("MealTrack");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1400, 600));
    setLocation(300, 100);
    setVisible(true);

    panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fill", "[grow][]", "[][][][grow][][]"));
    add(panel);
  panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control I"), new NewFoodAction());

    pack();
    filter.requestFocusInWindow();
}

private class NewFoodAction extends AbstractAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("called");
    }

}
```

}

Does anyone know what the problem seems to be?

Comment: *"I'm using MigLayout for the panel. Don't think this affects anything but who knows."*  You will if you swap it out for `FlowLayout` and the problem persists.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. **You need to use both ActionMap and InputMap**. You should do:

```
panel.getInputMap(con).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control I"), "createNewFood");
panel.getActionMap().put("createNewFood", new NewFoodAction());
```

Comment: Works! Reading the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)tutorial it says "Technically, you don't need to use action names in the maps; you can use any object as the "key" into the maps. By convention, however, you use a string that names an action". Also, how come I can use this format in other places? `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control F"), new GrabFocus());`

Comment: the reason is somewhere somebody must have registered action with "KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("cont‌​rol F")" as the key. You can also use any object as the key in input and action maps and need not be a string, the only requirement is that the key used must be same in both the maps.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Jcomponent documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#registerKeyboardAction%28java.awt.event.ActionListener,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.KeyStroke,%20int%29), you're mapping the key inputs, but the action they perform isn't actually mapped to the panel. for the code...
`panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control I"), "newfood!");`

... you must also have ...

```
panel.getActionMap().put("newfood!", [Some actionListener that does what you need to do]);
```

Not entirely sure that will correct the issue, but hopefully that fixes it for you. Good luck!